# 'allowed_types' are set but any format can be uploaded

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

This is my code:

```
config['upload_path'] = './media/resumes/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf|doc|docx';
            $config['max_size'] = '100000';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->do_upload("myfile");           

    //    enabling this code will result in duplication of uploaded file
        $file = $this->upload->data();
            $filename=$file['file_name'];
```

The problem is, I tried `.jpg` and even `.php`, and the files were successfully uploaded! no error!

Why is that and How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no any errors in the code, add this line `$this->upload->display_errors();` and check its working

```
$config['upload_path'] = './media/resumes/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf|doc|docx';
$config['max_size'] = '100000';

$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->upload->do_upload("myfile");

$this->upload->display_errors(); //add this line too
$file = $this->upload->data();

$filename = $file['file_name'];
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't make any differences!

Comment: Exactly! I don't get any error either! That's the problem! It should yield an error when files other than the specified ones are uploaded! but it doesn't!

Comment: check you code, is there any other place getting upload

Comment: There is, but that is for images and relevant file format.

Comment: If you copy that code to this also it should work fine. Check your code with any overflow areas or pointing  correct controller method and all. There is no any bit of error in our codes

Comment: figured out something: the uploaded files with other file formats than pdf, doc ad docx will not be stored in the path! This is good! but I have to handle the uploading file in my form! Not allowing the users to upload anything different than the specified formats

Comment: @Sean ok. How ever my code is working well and im using it in my live projects too

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

After this try to add

```
$this->upload->initialize($config);
```

may be it help you.

Comment: Both act same. No difference

Comment: and they both won't work!
I uploaded a sql file! lol! no changes! still accepts it!
Thanks for your efforts though!

Answer (score 0):

```
$config['upload_path'] = './media/resumes/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf|doc|docx';
$config['max_size'] = '100000';

$this->load->library('upload', $config);
if(!$this->upload->do_upload("myfile")){
$this->upload->display_errors();
}
else{
$file = $this->upload->data();
$filename = $file['file_name'];
}
```

Try this condition it should work..

Answer (score 0):

```
public function makeUpload($field, $place) {
            $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/' . $place;
            $config['allowed_types']        = 'png';
            $config['remove_spaces']        = TRUE;
            $config['encrypt_name']         = TRUE;
            $config['max_size']             = 30003072;

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $this->upload->do_upload($field);
            $errors = $this->upload->display_errors();
            if ($errors) {
                $this->error(array($errors));
            } else {
                $this->success(array($this->upload->data()));
            }
}

public function success($data){
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    http_response_code(200);
    die(json_encode($data));
}

public function error($data){
    http_response_code(404);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    die(json_encode($data));
}
```

And not forget the validation in html input, using

accept="image/*" or accept="application/pdf" more types in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file)